# Why does parsing this example Twitter json file via Angular $http fail and what can I do to fix it?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

I used the json example from this site (at the bottom) https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline, copied it to a file on my local file system and then tried to get it via Angular's $http service like this:

First I defined a service:

```
Services.TwitterService = function ($http) {
  'use strict';

  var TwitterService = {
    getHome: function () {
      return $http.get("ws/home.json").then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
      });
    }
  };

  return TwitterService;
};
```

Then in my controller:

```
  $scope.twitter = TwitterService;

  TwitterService.getHome().then(function (data) {
    $scope.twitter.home = data;
  });
```

Unfortunately when I run the code, there seems to be a problem with a "/" character in the json because I get this exception:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
>       at Object.parse (native)

Is Twitter's example json malformed or did I do something wrong?
If the json file is invalid what can I do to fix it? Do I have to replace all occurrences of "/"?

Comment: Yes, JSON example is broken, quotes are not escapted properly in "source" properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste the JSON in http://jsonlint.com/

It will validate the JSON code

The particular example you are mentioning seems not to be valid JSON.

```
Parse error on line 29:
..."source": "<a href="//realitytechnicians
-----------------------^
Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'
```

It looks like there is a problem with quotes... you can fix it manually and go ahead, I don't think it is a problem you will see with real responses from Twitter API